# Full Outer Join in Spring Data JPA with MySql Database

Tags: mysql, jpa, join, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have this example query and would like to do the Full Outer Join in the JPA as I am in the need of getting all the data for the sessions which are the part of this current session and were also involved in the previous along with the null values for those which are new. For that I am looking for a Full Outer Join in mysql but it is not supported. How would I do this in JPQL?

`"SELECT NEW com.example.UserNamesDTO(u1.name, u2.name) " + "FROM User u1 " + "INNER JOIN User u2 ON u1.cnicNumber = u2.cnicNumber " + "WHERE u1.sessionId = :sessionId1 AND u2.id = :userId2"`

Comment: FULL JOIN not implemented - so emulate it. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)? #5 and #3.

Comment: The workaround for MySQL to get the same result as a full outer join involves UNION, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/20860 I don't use JPQL, but I understand some providers do not support UNION. I have no idea if the JPQL provider for MySQL does or not.

Comment: @BillKarwin Unfortunately JPQL doesn't support the UNION or UNION ALL so will have to try with breaking up the query now.